# Show that $M=\{(x,y,u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^4 : x^2 + y^2 = u^2 + v^2 = 1\}$ is orientable, explaining the induced orientation.

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, manifolds, orientation

> Let $M=\{(x,y,u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^4 : x^2 + y^2 = u^2 + v^2 = 1\}$.
>
> 1. Show that $M$ is an orientable subvariety of $\mathbb{R}^4$, explaining the induced orientation.
> 2. Consider the $2$-form $\omega = a(x,y,u,v)dx \wedge du$ with $a \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^4)$. Compute $\int_M \omega$ in terms of $a$.

Showing that $M$ is a subvariety of $\mathbb{R}^4$ of dimension $2$ is not a problem.

So for 1., by definition, we need to find an everywhere (on $M$) non-vanishing $2$-form $\omega$.

How can I do that? (The same for induced orientation)

For 2. I have some ideas:

$$\int_M \omega = \int_{S^1 \times S^1} a(x,y,u,v)dx \wedge du = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} a(cosu,sinu,cosv,sinv) dudv$$

Is this true?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Let $d\theta =x ~dy - y ~ dx$ and $d\phi = u~dv - v~du$. Then $\omega = d\theta \wedge d\phi$ is such a 2-form.

For the second part, you're not quite on the right track: the parameterization by sine and cosines of two arguments -- $s$ and $t$ might have been better names -- is fine, but you can't just turn "dx" into "ds". Details:

Let
$$
X(s, t) = (\cos s, \sin s, \cos t, \sin t) 
$$
so that 
$$
x(s, t) = \cos s\\
y(s, t) = \sin s\\
u(s, t) = \cos t\\
v(s, t) = \sin t.
$$
Then observe that 
$$
dx = -\sin s ~ ds\\
du = -\sin t ~dt
$$
so that 
$$
dx \wedge du = \sin s \sin t ~ds \wedge dt.
$$
so your integral becomes
$$
\int_{[0, 2\pi] \times [0, 2\pi]} a(\cos s, \sin s, \cos t, \sin t) \sin s \sin t ~ ds \wedge dt.
$$

I can never remember what to do at this last step, and always have to look up an example in Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* -- do I need a factor of 1/2? Do I have to integrate ds dt and then integrate dt ds or ... well, as I say, I can't recall. I think that in practice you just drop the wedge and integrate, but I could easily be wrong. :(

Comment: Thanks for answering. What was your idea to take that $\omega$? Can you explain me how to explicit the induced orientation? Thanks

Comment: Since I knew that the surface you'd described is a torus, I said "a volume form on $S^1 \times S^1$ is just the product of the volume form on the two individual factors. And on $S^1$ itself, the form $x dy - y dx$ is pretty much a classic : It's the thing that when integrated around the circle gives $2\pi$ (basically by doing a contour integral like the ones you learned in complex variables). So I just took the product of two of those. I don;t understand your last question -- did you lose a verb? -- so I can't answer...and I have to run off and meet someone in 1 minute...

Comment: A few more details about the final integration added... but not a complete answer. It's been too long since I needed to actually compute anything with a differential form.

Comment: I think it is right (I forgot to put $sin(u) sin(v)$ in the integral) and I think that we can erase the wedge